# create ROS workspace - command not found

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed:
ROS Indigo
Trusty (14.04)

I'm stuck in the ROS installation at
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment
3. Managing your environment

When I run the command:

```
$ export | grep ROS
```

The terminal outputs:

```
$: command not found
```

The same thing happens when I attempt any of the commands there after on the guide.

**Checking ROS Installation**

When I run the command:

```
which roscore
```

The terminal outputs:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roscore
```

**Attempting to uninstall ROS**

When I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros
```

The terminal outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217301/create-ros-workspace---command-not-found/) by [Dallas Chase](https://answers.ros.org/users/23799/dallas-chase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-09-08**:
Is your shell a bash? The first "command not found" error looks odd. apt-get remove ros won't work, because there is no package named ros. To uninstall put the packages you used from the install tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command is `export | grep ROS`. You have put a $ sign before that, that's why you are getting that error!

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-09-08**:
This is the solution to the problem, so I converted this to an answer.